# Amazon S3 Transfer Acceleration does not improve upload speed

Tags: amazon-s3

I am uploading small photos (~40k) to s3.

I am trying to improve the speed, so I turned on the acceleration option.

Tests I run on my Android device show no differences with/without acceleration.

Obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Has anyone bumped into this issue?

I tried AWS forums, but looks like nobody bother to answer questions there...

TEST:

Uploading a ~4M file repeatedly with and without accelerator. Each row describes the url and the time in MS the upload took.

```html
With acceleration took 402 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/5a530ba8-dd8e-43eb-b9ab-ff19fe4c7251.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826309&Signature=I64fDwertgCp2YhkWHsCtT2jAh4%3D
Without acceleration took 514 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/950779b8-0e03-4baf-9986-94d7cf207780.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826309&Signature=jsLKDfxHHxzrTd3YwertjvoES4%3D
With acceleration took 435 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/9a4db3d7-1411-449f-83ec-f66d96e5957e.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826309&Signature=ViuP%2BVgwI1ertpiCV8%2BZ%2FI1eRw%3D
Without acceleration took 545 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/33f28616-ed24-41cb-88a9-5a081d31f694.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826309&Signature=Xg4sHX3Hc1TzKsNV49wertjgT1g%3D
With acceleration took 421 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/943bd34f-367a-4ba9-bb30-f4b97e76b90f.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826309&Signature=jaXOq6Zz2Dh%2F6Hertrf%2BNLGfA6M%3D
Without acceleration took 394 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/893adfa8-714d-4970-9292-d18006aea416.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826310&Signature=gEjk9HzDV3wertPAGkiq0vsXYfA%3D
With acceleration took 443 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/80dd1c1a-f704-43c1-8603-ea184473d9dc.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826310&Signature=RF1%2FLpVwertTZTNcTANZuvRSEQU%3D
Without acceleration took 443 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/33062018-f03b-487e-abed-c66600485eda.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826310&Signature=Q0ColhcQ23fQ2iGSiZZ%2wertqlc%3D
With acceleration took 443 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/37f7969a-2abd-4970-97a4-d1bd8791527d.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826310&Signature=ZYO5GNBFJSUJertDiRccSdkHU%3D
Without acceleration took 468 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/3a48f284-f12e-46ab-a848-54cf156d5425.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826310&Signature=s6MSlFZLHQ9%2FSYa%2Bwertvo3yWQ%3D
With acceleration took 482 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/4c90c9b6-4881-4d21-b81c-06186e976656.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826311&Signature=h87XYQ8E2mIerttoej6LMi5Lw%3D
Without acceleration took 481 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/f5e3f395-b003-424b-a668-d5eb7cf1f7e7.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826311&Signature=uTt54sbgni7q%2Ff%2FJwertQyz8LQs%3D
With acceleration took 483 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/c43cecdf-e0e4-4605-9b7d-550261352970.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826311&Signature=gX1vSDKq1mCwertgPJT0NtGXrs%3D
Without acceleration took 353 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/9d7d9c82-f734-4707-a881-e099526f5d25.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826311&Signature=rU4VvJlDxp46VUgw5rynsAZnh94%3D
With acceleration took 617 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/e58936ea-87ae-4cf5-bc1d-46ffe4b3dc87.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826313&Signature=2X821N5ZgerccuFkoFkcg9KChsR8%3D
Without acceleration took 404 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/ebd92c90-6059-4f9e-b6c3-f7a2e145e5c6.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826313&Signature=ns%2FSMWuegbwcWQe5ctw5khykpx1ZY%3D
With acceleration took 786 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/091ad909-515b-4413-83b9-589bef68d53c.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826315&Signature=JZYiiTpDgcerwefzGUvBKbrMJZy0U%3D
Without acceleration took 508 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/52289de3-09ac-4cfc-9c51-3f18f16bf4dd.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826316&Signature=USn7NmvhtBo9Ubxvretgvdfq6Kjd9M%3D
With acceleration took 460 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/41dfba81-8127-4c32-85b0-0048249c31d3.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826316&Signature=CXzH8A0pwergwrvXg26Kif6ggNoaA%3D
Without acceleration took 1051 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/6a7cd5e3-494d-4fc4-9c58-7e406b54cff5.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826316&Signature=1%2FeYhO9He5zcert5cy25wkIxVyk%3D
With acceleration took 523 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/f440a87f-908d-4721-9eaf-34d760853120.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826316&Signature=8e4GJ31hgxzwhqpTUjvJh%2BBJ9ew%3D
Without acceleration took 468 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/feb9d3c6-dc7b-492b-ad45-98072658d13b.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826316&Signature=kiB8iSDjhi6lTGE5cgw66F0m%2BLsx9w%3D
With acceleration took 541 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/211f7ead-b73d-4e24-822e-82e5a3d65f8f.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826317&Signature=uqXaBjlucegwercnwEomcKyYoMHBU%3D
With acceleration took 509 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/27949195-00e7-4cd8-b8a7-972e7505e0a1.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826317&Signature=vBzimpeL%2FhttcspuWEZgLgnuex%2BiI%3D
Without acceleration took 899 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/6c42af02-3b9a-45fe-b648-2bfb94300bae.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826317&Signature=x%2FSgLkp%2BhtvRPLXwWAnntrhgfdg%3D
Without acceleration took 472 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/bf824bf9-1103-470c-9b66-03a6f84b817d.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826317&Signature=1bwLJhfPt%2FqSp0uNuvcgbdf6fQ0rw%3D
With acceleration took 432 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/f98c3fbe-98d2-415d-8c4c-f465ae45221c.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826317&Signature=wapRwe8RGpB%2BhtyhgtPqnu%2FGpk%3D
Without acceleration took 491 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/86d8ca4f-689f-4f64-aca0-0bea905d22d5.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826317&Signature=%2BRkr9YDwotTDIcrggtPcLzX0sU%3D
With acceleration took 481 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/d7513f73-e4cc-40e3-a27f-8a233dee8ee9.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826317&Signature=CZcZlhj4Wcrtgfrdic5sXW0qPCxTs%3D
Without acceleration took 472 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/8447eb80-ce14-4799-ad7c-54d9522d3611.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826318&Signature=jY3RpdW9TU%2FaTvfgbdftS4ruU0Bo%3D
With acceleration took 606 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/bd955ea1-5456-4d8a-837f-4b8139ef4ed4.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826318&Signature=eEI%2BgfetrdfgWeYxUYVT%2BRAIhMbI%3D
Without acceleration took 360 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/8c59250f-89c7-4305-b2d9-f1ef2fe9ffea.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826318&Signature=Mk9MsiE5NKqEvpZ9rgfdfcvA%2B7h8%3D
With acceleration took 606 MS https://bucket-test.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/919b0c34-108b-445a-aff5-da3db40d4f0c.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826318&Signature=YtN%2BmcrtgrtfuRH9%2BRFpVW4VojvdU%3D
Without acceleration took 367 MS https://bucket-test.s3.amazonaws.com/personal_photos_images/28d08720f6b385b5_112120161528/resize/31981415-0274-466e-940d-2f0cdeddbf07.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=QKMMDYRGKDJJJDIZNMCA&Expires=1479826318&Signature=UNYAredXIfskcnZgertgyhgJFVmxkJU%3D
```

Region: default, N. Virginia.
[image]

Comment: Where in the world are you located? In which region is the destination bucket located? Transfer Acceleration is only advantageous for transferring data over long distances (eg between countries).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm in Israel, region is N. Virginia.

Answer (score 0):

AWS has a tool to test if transfer acceleration helps for a specific situation, it should give a definite answer: http://s3-accelerate-speedtest.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com/en/accelerate-speed-comparsion.html

Comment: Should be 30% faster. See attached screenshot of AWS test in the question.

Comment: Then the issue is probably the file size. The files may be just to small to see any effect. In the FAQ AWS says: "If you have objects that are smaller than 1GB or if the data set is less than 1GB in size, you should consider using Amazon CloudFront's PUT/POST commands for optimal performance."

Comment: If we upload object to transfer acceleration enabled bucked using aws console , How its become useful